# PDEs, method of characteristics for quasi linear equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am struggling to understand where a line comes from in the following solution to a question:

Solve the Cauchy problem:
$ u_x + uu_y=0$
 and $u(0,y)=y$

To start the question I set
$x_\xi = 1$, $y_\xi=u$ and $u_\xi=0$
By setting $\xi=0$ the next line of the solution becomes
$x(0,\eta)=0, y(0,\eta)=\eta$ and $u(0,\eta)=\eta$
This is the line that is giving me difficulty, but I understand the rest of the solution. Where does it come from?

Comment: Its a parametrisation that  comes from the fact that $u(0,y)=y$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$u_x+uu_y=0$$
Writing the differential equations
$$
\begin{align}
\frac {dx}{ds}=&1  \implies x=s+c_1\\
\frac {dy}{ds}=&z \\ 
\frac {dz}{ds}=&0  \implies z=c_3 \\
\end{align}
$$
Now the second DE can be solved :
$$ \frac {dy}{ds}=z\implies \frac {dy}{ds}=c_3$$
$$ y(s)=c_3s+c_2$$

$u(0,y)=y$ 
Can be rewritten as
$$ x(0)=0, y(0)=\eta, z(0)=\eta$$
We can find the constants now:
$$
\begin{align}
x(s)&=s+c_1 \implies c_1=x(0)=0 \implies x(s)=s \\
z(s)&=c_3 \implies c_3=\eta \implies z(s) =\eta \\
y(s)&=c_3s+c_2=\eta s+c_2 \implies c_2=\eta \\
\implies y(s)&=\eta(s+1) \\
\end{align}
$$
Finally:
$$z=\eta=\frac y {s+1}=\frac y {x+1}$$
$$ z(x,y)=\frac y{x+1}$$